Confirming the angle between intersecting planes using projections
Let's say I have 2 planes:
$$\text{Plane}_1: x + 2y - z = 3$$
and
$$\text{Plane}_2: 2x -y +3z = 4$$
which have normal vectors of $[1,2,-1]$ and $[2,-1,3]$ respectively.
It's clear that the normal vectors are not a scalar multiple of each other.
The angle between the normal vectors can be found with
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{n_1 \cdot n_2}{||n_1||\ ||n_2||},$$
so the angle between the planes is $109.1$ degrees.
I wanted to confirm this (just for fun) using an alternative method, using the following steps.

Find the equation of the line, $l$ where the two planes intersect.
Find a point on this line, $l_1$.
Get a point $p_1$ on $\text{Plane}_1$, to get a vector from the line to $\text{Plane}_1$ (a.k.a. $l_1p_1$).
Get the projection vector, $\text{proj}_1$, of $l_1p_1$ onto the line.
Get direction vector, $d_1$, from line to $p_1$ (a.k.a. $l_1p_1 - \text{proj}_1$).
Repeat steps 3, 4, 5 to get direction vector $d_2$ from intersection line to a point in $\text{Plane}_2$.
Use $\cos$ angle formula used above for $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Visually I think it would be valid, but I am unable to confirm the angle obtained with normal vectors.
My results for the steps are as follows:

Equation of $l$: $[\frac{11}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, 0] + t[-1, 1, 1]$ for some real $t$.

Point $l_1$ at $t = 0$: $[\frac{11}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, 0]$.

Point $p_1$ on $\text{Plane}_1$: $[1,1,0]$. Vector $l_1p_1 = p_1 - l_1 = [1,1,0] - [\frac{11}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, 0] = [-\frac{6}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, 0]$.

Projection ($\text{proj}_1$) of $l_1p_1$ onto direction vector $l$ which is [-1,1,1]:
$$\frac{l \cdot l_1p_1}{l \cdot l} \, l = [-\frac{3}{5}, \frac{3}{5},\frac{3}{5}]$$

Direction vector ($d_1$) from intersection line to $p_1$: $l_1p_1 - \text{proj}_1 = [-\frac{3}{5}, 0, -\frac{3}{5}]$.

Let $p_2 = [1,1,1]$ so $l_1p_2 = [-\frac{6}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, 1]$

$\text{proj}_2$:
$$\frac{l \cdot l_1p_2}{l \cdot l} \, l = [-\frac{14}{15}, \frac{14}{15}, \frac{14}{15}]$$

$d_2$: $[-\frac{4}{15}, -\frac{5}{15}, \frac{1}{15}]$

Angle between $d_1$ and $d_2$ = $70.9$ degrees so above is correct.



The angle IS $109.11°$; so, if your second method is right, there is simply a calculus mistake.

Firstly there is ambiguity in your notation. It is not clear what $l$ is. At the start you say that it is a line but then you treat it as a vector when you compute a dot product.
Also when you compute the projection we would expect to obtain a point which lies on the line $l$ however this is not the case.
Indeed solving $[11/5,2/5,0]+t[−1,1,1] = [2/5,−2/5,−2/5]$ for $t$ gives no solutions.
Also don't overcomplicate things just take $t = 0$ if you are looking for a point on the line.

In fact the issue is that you are not computing the projection correctly.
In order to find the projection of the point $p_1$ onto the line $l_1$ you should rather consider a direction vector for the line - take $v =  (-1,1,1)$ - and project the vector $l_1p_1$ on the direction vector $v$. This gives you a scalar $\lambda$.
Then the projection of $p_1$ onto the line $l$ is
$$ l_1 + \lambda v.$$

Thank you. I've made some corrections and found the angle between the direction vectors to confirm what was found between normal vectors.

My only question now is, after the 4th step, shouldn't the projection vector yield a solution for the intersection line?

@achacttn Indeed. As you can see $l_1 + \lambda v$ is a point on the line $l$.

Thanks. I can see now that the vector l_1proj_1 is a solution to the intersection line.
